# UITableView willDisplay keeps calling itself when calling the API pagination, Issue is with async API Calling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mvvm, delegates

I am using MVVM and this tableview delegate is in ViewController
**The issue is because of API calling function using ViewModel object**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == photosVM.albumData.photos!.photo!.count - 1 {
        if photosVM.albumData.photos!.pages! >= photosVM.albumData.photos!.page! {
            spinner.color = UIColor.FlickrAlbum_theme
            spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .medium)
            spinner.startAnimating()
            spinner.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: tableView.bounds.width, height: CGFloat(44))
            tblPhotos.tableFooterView = spinner
            tblPhotos.tableFooterView?.isHidden = false
                //Calling search API with search keywords
                photosVM.getPhotos(pageNumber: photosVM.albumData.photos!.page! + 1, searchText: txtSearch.text!) { [self] (status) in
                    lblDescription.text = txtSearch.text
                    if status == "success" {
                        lblDescription.text = txtSearch.text
                        tblPhotos.reloadData()
                    }
                    else {
                        //showing error message
                        showAlert(message: status)
                    }
                }
            spinner.stopAnimating()
            tblPhotos.tableFooterView = nil
            tblPhotos.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true
        }
   }
```

and here is my ViewModel in which I have a function of calling the API and binding data to the view controller

```
func getPhotos(pageNumber: Int = 1, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    let params = GetPhotosBody()
    params.format = "json"
    params.apiKey = Constants.apiKey
    params.nojsoncallback = 1
    params.page = pageNumber
    params.text = ""
    params.contentType = 1
    ServerManager.getAllPhotos(params: params) { [self] (status, data) in
        if status == "success" {
            if pageNumber == 1 {
                albumData = data
            }
            else {
                 albumData.photos?.page = data?.photos?.page!
                 albumData.photos?.photo?.append(contentsOf: (data!.photos!.photo!))
            }
            //Cache Data
             DataCache.instance.write(object: albumData.toJSON() as NSCoding, forKey: CacheValue.photos)
        }
        if let photos = DataCache.instance.readObject(forKey: CacheValue.photos) {
            albumData = Mapper<FlickrAlbumPhotosResponse>().map(JSONObject: photos)
       }
       else {
           albumData = nil
       }
        completion(status)
    }
}
```

and this is API calling manager I am using completionblock to handle the async approach

```
public static func getAllPhotos(params: GetPhotosBody, completion: @escaping (String ,FlickrAlbumPhotosResponse?) -> Void) {
    //creating URL
    //addingPercentEncoding is used for encoding the url string to support text with spaces
    let url = "\(Constants.baseURL)\(FlickrAlbumEndpoints.getPhotos.rawValue)&format=\(String(describing: params.format!))&nojsoncallback=\(String(describing: params.nojsoncallback!))&api_key=\(String(describing: params.apiKey!))&page=\(String(describing: params.page!))".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
    //creating request
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.get.rawValue
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    //Making request to the server to call the API
    Alamofire.request(request).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<FlickrAlbumPhotosResponse>) in
        //Check the response of the API
        switch response.result {
            case .success:
                let data = response.result.value
                completion("success",data)
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(error.localizedDescription, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I turn off the internet its keeps showing error message again and again because it keeps calling the will display delegate.
If I am using MVVM in the wrong way please do let me know and give your suggestion. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect that you are assigning some cached data to your view model array when api call fails (because of no internet). Assigning it triggers your binding function in view controller which reloads tableview and thus api call is made again entering you in an endless loop.

Remove the cache assigning from your api function and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It keeps showing error message because the table is reloading its data again and again on `getSearchPhotos` completion block.

Reload data will call table view delegate and then this process will be on loop.

```
photosVM.getSearchPhotos(pageNumber: photosVM.albumData.photos!.page! + 1, searchText: txtSearch.text!) { [self] (status) in
    lblDescription.text = txtSearch.text
    tblPhotos.reloadData() // why reload here?

    // the rest of the code
}
```

uncomment the first reload code and reload the data if its success calling API.

Comment: I removed that but error is still the same :(

Comment: Actually, the issue is with the async call of the API. I am calling the ViewModel function from VC and ViewModel function is calling the API function.

Comment: That is how it supposed to work, VC should not directly call API. Just curious, what is your `photosVM.albumData.photos!.photo!` structure looks like?

Comment: its an array of images with some other attributes. The model works perfectly fine.
Is there any other way to call the API from VC using MVVM.

Comment: By the way when I am calling the API Function directly from VC then it works fine. problem is calling the API function from viewmodel.

Comment: How do you call the API from VC?

Comment: I have a function in ViewModel which calls the Servermanager Function which is for API and from VC I am calling the ViewModel function. And I mentioned my code above you can see that.

Comment: By the way when I am calling the API Function directly from VC then it works fine <- How do you do that? No function on your code above does this. Edit your question to include this so we can look what went wrong.

Comment: No, I am just telling you that this issue doesn't appear if I call the API from VC. I want the API Call in this order: 
VC -> ViewModel -> API Call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231821/discussion-between-hassan-shahid-and-seto-nugroho).

Answer (score 0):

I just removed these lines from the ViewModel function and now it is working fine.

```
 if let photos = DataCache.instance.readObject(forKey: CacheValue.photos) {
        albumData = Mapper<FlickrAlbumPhotosResponse>().map(JSONObject: photos)
   }
   else {
       albumData = nil
   }
```

Now, I handled that cache when ViewModel initialize, which is in constructor.